# Time Intelligence Functions in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a measure in DAX (Power BI) that calculates "YTD Revenue" to calculate year-to-date total revenue.

I have used `CALCULATE(Measure, DATESYTD(Calendar[Date]))` as my formula for the question but I'm a bit confused about what "Measure" and "Calendar Date" to use within the formula since the result set does *not* match the spot check number provided to me as a reference point.

Comment: Can you add an example and expected outcome as you say it not matching your spot check number

Comment: I have some tables with data that i am working on and one of them is a calendar table that has "Date", "Start of Month", "End of Month", "Month" and "Year" columns among others. The data is for TWO YEARS (1/1/1997-12/31/1998). The question is "Create a new measure named "YTD Revenue" to calculate year-to-date total revenue, and format as $...
•Spot check: Create a matrix with "Start of Month" on rows; you should see $872,924 in YTD Revenue in September 1998. The Dax formula I have applied is "YTD Revenue = CALCULATE([Total Revenue],DATESYTD('Calendar'[Start of Month] ))...Thanks Jon

Comment: A few things to add to my above inquiry, "Total Revenue" is a measure I have already created for another requirement and "Start of Month" is a column in the table. What i have is 1,199,308.31 as a result instead of the $872,924. I just started learning Power Bi so I do appreciate all the help i can get...

Answer (score 0):

For any time intelligence, it is recommended that you have a defined calendar table, as for calculations such parallel period, need a full date range to work, were as the date ranges in your dataset may have gaps in it. You also must flag your calendar table as a 'Mark as date table'.

[image]

For the [DATESYTD](https://dax.guide/datesytd/) function, you need to add two items. From your example

```
CALCULATE([Total Revenue],DATESYTD('Calendar'[Start of Month]))
```

Assuming that the [Total Revenue] measure is a basic sum of revenue, then the next step can be the date in your dataset or the column in the related calendar table. However it is recommend that you use a related calendar table. In the example below, there is a column in the calendar table called 'Month Begin'.

[image]

The measure 'Values With Time Intel' will aggregate for the whole month. In this case each day has a value of 1.

An example file of the set up is [here](https://github.com/itconsultantonthedge/PowerBIExampleFiles/blob/master/SO_Question_62868125.pbix).

Comment: I checked to see if the dataset for gaps but it's a full date range. The Calendar table is also related to the data table. If you were to calculate a YTD for multiple years, what formula would you use to build your measure ? Also if it does help, Total Revenue was calculated using Total Revenue = SUMX(Products,Products[product_retail_price] * [Quantity Sold]) in my case. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing a Dax on your own.
You will have "QuickMeasure" option.
[See the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyxJh.png)
The Power Bi has already provided some calculated daxes .
YTD calculation is also one of that.

1)Use a quick measure
2)Select the "Year to date total" under time intelligence function after you selected the quick measure
3)Give a base value column and date you are refering for YTD total.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question, they have created the measure but having an issue with its output.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Power Bi and it was suggested NOT to use Quick measures when possible but I have checked what you suggested and I am even more confused because the data I have is for two years(1997 and 1998) and I do have a calendar table with date and month columns but when using quick measures,I could only select column names for base value and not specific dates or months ..•Create a new measure named "YTD Revenue" to calculate year-to-date total revenue, and format as $
•Spot check: Create a matrix with "Start of Month" on rows; you should see $872,924 in YTD Revenue in September 1998

Comment: The very last statements in my previous comment are the actual question I am dealing with..How do you add September 1998 in the formula to be created is what i am dealing with now in order to follow your suggestions. thanks

Comment: Could you please add screenshot from your calendar table and fact table? also please check if your calendar date based column is joined to fact table date column correctly in relationship view.

Comment: @AjayKumar, the comment box here only accepts text. Pardon my silly question but how do i paste my screenshot to provide what you've asked above ? thanks